# jQuery get value, data- of dropdown with the same class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm building a custom add to cart system. One product can have many criteria such as color, size etc. These criteria can be added dynamically in the backend.

Now in the front end, I use php to fetch all the dynamic criteria to my product page. The script is as follows:

```
<form class="cart">
<div class="add-to-cart-table">


      <?php 


$sqlac = "SELECT * FROM sym_product_option WHERE product_id = '$pk'";
$stmtac = $dbo->prepare($sqlac);
$stmtac->execute();
while($rowac = $stmtac->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 

            $huhu = $rowac["option_id"];
        $sqlag = "SELECT * FROM sym_product_option_value WHERE option_id = '$huhu'";
        $stmtag = $dbo->prepare($sqlag);
        $stmtag->execute();

    ?>
    <div class="option">
        <?php echo $rowac["option_name"]; ?> 
        <select name="" class="form-control" class="option" onchange="calc()" data-option-id="<?php echo $rowac["option_"]; ?>" >
            <?php while($rowag = $stmtag->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 

            if($rowag["value_price"] == "0.00"){
                $demson = "";
            } else {
                $demson = "Add-On RM ".$rowag["value_price"];
            }
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $rowag["value_id"]; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $rowag["value_price"]; ?>"><?php echo $rowag["value_name"]." ".$demson; ?> </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div style="margin-top: 30px;" >
      <button type="button" class="button" onclick="addtocart();" style="width:100%;">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I'm wondering how to use jquery to fetch each criteria ID(data-option-id), criteria option value(select dropdown value) and combine them into an array to be sent to php backend. I think the array should look like this:

```
$data = array ( "0"  => array ( "option-id" => "1", "option-value" => "5"), "1"  => array ( "option-id" => "2", "option-value" => "8"));
```

Can someone help me on this? Really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is about your frontend. Please show the relevant frontend (html+js) code, not the backend to generate it. 
Apart from that, what has been your approach so far? Please do not expect stackoverflow to write your code. Do your own research on ajax and jquery, then please [ask a more specifiy question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why handle that via arbitrary custom data attributes to begin with? I’d put that info into the field name directly (“array syntax”, `name="option[47]"`) - that gives you an array structure on the receiving end in PHP, and you can use standard methods such a jQuery’s serialize to create the form data set, instead of having to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to add a start and end form tag surrounding the option dropdowns. After that you can use the code below to serialize the form and send it to the server with ajax

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
});
```